# How to get content from HttpServletReponse in spring boot interceptors

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, interceptor

```
public class ActivityLogInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
public ActivityLogInterceptor() {
    super();
}

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

    // I need the response here that has been returned in the rest api
    super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
}
```

}

This is springboot HandlerInterceptorAdapter, I need the response body in the postHandle which has been sent by the rest api.  I have tried the outputstream which doesn't work, I get null value when tried to convert to object.

[image]

please checkout above image for HttpServletResponse's methods where I could not find content or body to get the exact response, even the ModelView is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        ContentCachingResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ContentCachingResponseWrapper(response);
        System.out.println(responseWrapper.getContentAsByteArray());
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
```

`ContentCachingResponseWrapper` is to get content from the ServletResponse.  I could see the response result in the swagger from the REST API but when I tried to print it the content lenght is 0.

[image]

above image shows the result from the rest api, but when I tried to get the content in interceptors is empty and the content lenght is 0.

Answer (score -1):

this should do the trick:

```
@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
    final PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
    System.out.println(writer.toString());
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply :) but I get exception ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response```